# Can ADVI (Variational Inference) Induce Weak Multi Modality in a system with Uniform Priors, if a Gaussian Variational Family is Used

Tags: optimization, variational-bayes, transform

**Question Set Up**

If I have a *weakly* multi modal (see below in the edit) target posterior distribution which I am aiming to approximate using ADVI (Automatic Differentiation Variational Inference) with the following two conditions:

1. The variational family is full rank Gaussian (which is therefore uni modal)
2. The prior for the latent variables are uniform distributions

**My Question:**

Is it possible for the converged variational solution in the real, physical space to exhibit slightly multi-modal behaviour (since the target was multi modal), even though the variational family is full rank Gaussian?

**Additional  Notes**

The authors of the ADVI paper state that since optimization is performed in a transformed space, it is likely that the distribution in the original space need not look Gaussian (even though it was selected for in the variational modeling step).

In addition, since transforming uniform priors to $\mathbb{R}^D$ requires logistic functions, I was wondering if it is therefore possible to induce slightly multi modal behaviour in the original space given this set-up.

Link to ADVI paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00788

Showcase of how the transformation of the uniform distribution to $\mathbb{R}^D$ is highly non linear, which is what makes me suspicious.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421052/117574

EDIT:

- I define weak multi-modality to be the case of when I have a say, a GMM which overlaps in a majority of its density amongst each Gaussian. This way you can get one *Gaussian-like* shape with multiple peaks.
- I define strong multi-modality to be the converse. A GMM with very well separated Gaussian components. They overlap with very little probability mass. *I am not concerned with this case*.

I demonstrate my definition of *weak multi-modality* as follows:

[image]